# Create a grid from figures python

Tags: python, numpy

Im new to python, Im trying to create a 3X4 grid figure of 12 figures, ￼the figures looks like that :

[image]
￼

￼[image]

I use this code to make them shown :

```
for i in range(0,11):
    show(x_train[i].reshape(28,28))
```

Where show is defined as follows :

```
def show(mnst):
    plt.figure() 
    plt.imshow(mnst, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest') 
    plt.show()
```

now my attempt to do what i am trying to do is as follows :

```
show(x_train[:12].reshape(28*3,28*4));
```

I read this code as take 12 first figures from x_train, which are 28X28 each, and reshape the whole thing to 3X4 grid of 28X28 figures in one figure.

But for some reason I get this weird 12X4 figure :
￼

[image]

What am i missing?
￼

￼

￼

￼

￼

￼

￼

￼

Comment: It seems x_train is a (12 x 784) shaped array? When you're reshaping it the way you are, the first image (that is a flattened 28x28 image) has its first 3 rows of pixels smeared out over the first 1 row. The second row of pixels that you see are the 4th, 5th and 6th rows of pixels of your actual first image, etc. Could this be causing your problem?

Comment: I think that it may occur, because you are resharping 28x12*28 array, not 1x12 array. First 3 lines are then the first lines of each picture, not 3 first lines of 4 pictures.

Comment: @Haminaa Yes, but even if i do x_train[:12].flatten() and then reshape(28*3,28*4) i still get same results, as im trying to learn i would appriciate if you guys can lead me in the right direction how to fix my solution... (a solution using reshapes of the 12X784 array)

Comment: Then I think you want to do the following:
`np.vstack(np.array([np.hstack(i) for i in x_train.reshape(3,4,28,28)]))`
Let me know if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over the function you are using results in a new `figure` instance created at each iteration. If you want to plot multiple images you'll want to create a single `figure` containing multiple subplots.

There are many ways to create subplots in a single figure in python. One that I often use (and seems to be what you need) is `plt.subplots()`. You can initiate your figure as follows:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots( 3,4, figsize=[12,9] )
```

This returns a figure instance `fig`, and an array of axes (an ax is the frame in which you plot your image) of 3 rows and 4 columns.
You can then plot (or .imshow) in each ax by looping over the axes.

```
for i,iax in enumerate( axes.flatten() ):
    iax.imshow(x_train[i].reshape(28,28), cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
fig.show()
```

Note that I flattened the array containing the axes. This does not change the layout of the subplots because it does not affect the `ax` instances that were created with `plt.subplots()`.

Comment: If you re-read the question you notice that i iterated the images just to see them and to show you examples of them. Then i did this show(x_train[:12].reshape(28*3,28*4)); and that should have worked, im trying to understand why that didnt work...

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to solve your problem more so that answering the question. I added a comment to your original question